# how to disable manage-resolv-conf in cloud-init

Tags: openstack

In my OpenStack instance, resolv.conf is automatically updating with below entries:

```
search openstacklocal
nameserver 10.10.10.21
nameserver 10.10.10.22
nameserver 10.10.10.20
```

I dont want any DNS entries in my resolv.conf file. I have tried `manage-resolv-conf: false` in cloud.cfg file but no luck.